# IE 8 CSS Pie Box-Shadow Overflow Issue

Tags: css, overflow, css3pie

I have a drop shadow (box-shadow) on my header element which runs 100% of the top of the page. I've added a CSS Pie to enable box-shadows in IE8 , but it seems like css pie has added a margin, or some spacing to the right of the header causing it to over flow and allowing the user to scroll to reveal empty margins.

I've tried setting `overflow-x:hidden` but that on the header, the child element and the parent and have also tried setting a position relative on the element but none of that actually works. Has any one else had this issue, and how were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. It's a bit embarrassing, and I swore I tried this fix before, but apparently now. It was quite a very simple fix.

I just set the styles of the body to overflow-x:hidden.

```
body { 
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

That simply removed the scroll bar and hid everything outside of the immediate browser window.